# Design tetris game

Tags: c

Recently, I was interviewed at some good company and was asked to design the tetris game with efficient data structures. I answered to 2D array for each shape, but interviewer was looking for a better answer. Then, he asked me to design Ludo also.

Any inputs on both these questions?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how to do Ludo, but the first thing that comes to mind for Tetris is to use a bit mask.

You can make a 'super shape' that would be large enough to include all the shapes in tetris and then turn on bits in the mask to make 'shapes'.

This way each shape can be of the same object type. When they 'land' you can turn on bits in a much larger bit mask that represents the board. when the right sets of bits are all on 'made a line' you can handle the event.

Answer (score 4):

A decent choice would be a list of three pairs of offsets from an *origin* for each piece (the fourth offset is `{0.0}`). This would let you encode [shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris) as follows:

```
I  {0,1}  {0,2}  {0,3}
J  {0,1}  {1,1}  {2,1}
L  {0,1}  {-1,1} {-2,1}
O  {0,1}  {1,1}  {1,0}
S  {-1,0} {-1,1} {-2,1}
T  {-1,1} {0,1}  {1,1}
Z  {1,0}  {1,1}  {2,1}
```

With these lists in hand you would be able to draw shapes, check the "glass" for space availability for the corresponding shape, apply rotation, and place inside the glass at their final resting place. Unlike 2D structures that would require two nested loops for most operations, this structure would let you do testing with a single loop, or even without a loop if you [unroll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) its trivial four steps.